# Adding Event to AuthController in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I seen this question before I just wanted help clarifying it.

The goal is to Fire an event when someone registers to the site.

I added the Event/Listener Pair in the Event Service Provider as noted in the Laravel Documentation.

Then I ran the: php artisan command
php artisan generate:event

When a user signs up at example.com/register it should trigger that event. However it does not.

Any Suggestions?

app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php

```
 protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
        Event::fire(new NewUserSignUp($data));
    }
```

The whole file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use App\Events\NotifyAdminSignUp;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/';

/**
 * Create a new authentication controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
    Event::fire(new NewUserSignUp($data));
}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected function create(array $data)
{ 
    //fire event BEFORE return
    Event::fire(new NewUserSignUp($data));
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
    //because nothing after this line will ever be processed

}
```